# Google Checkout - Force callback URL API post

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I'm building a Magento cart and we set up Google Checkout and went live and unfortunately I was unaware of the 'API Callback URL' setting on the Google side and didn't have that filled in until now. So now we have a few orders that went through and I need to get them into my cart system so I'm wondering if there's a way to force post existing orders across to my system?

Answer (score 0):

See this document for various ways to retrieve Googe Checkout notifications.

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Polling_API.html

In your case try the Polling API or the Notification History API.